# Unity tank multiplayer

Tags: game-engine, multiplayer, unity-game-engine

I am a begginer in unity and I making tank game with this [tutorial series](http://youtu.be/arRfqr3CJ2w). How to I can add multiplayer to my game(damage, score, network view )? Is there any (detailed) tutorial for this or assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for multiplayer networking is [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNet.html), and a google search for "unity multiplayer tutorial" comes up with some good tutorials, including [this one](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-5-unet-multiplayer-tutorials-making-a-basic-survival-co-op.325692/).
Hope this helps!